# How does one populate a pre-designed spreadsheet with Java?

Tags: java

I may be going about this the wrong way, but here's the goal:

I want to populate specific fields (that are color keyed) in a spreadsheet with both the figures input by the user and the solutions made by those inputs. The spreadsheet does not have to be interactive. Essentially, (without being able to find the solution) I am trying to pass a variable into a specific cell in a spreadsheet. I could achieve this with Access or Excel, but this is a small part of a larger application. If it helps, ultimately, the user inputs and calcs need to be stored in a database and organized/keyed by date; there will be new inputs and calculations entered daily. Here's my test program:

```
/* 
    Test program to generate spreadsheet and populate specific cells 
    with the scanner inputs from the user and the solution derived
    from scanner inputs
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

class TestRecord {
    String name;
    double a;
    double b;


    double calc_average() {
        double x = (a+b) / 2;
        System.out.println("The average is " + x);
        return x;
    }
}

class SheetGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    TestRecord dingdong = new TestRecord();

        double calculatedAverage;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        dingdong.name = "Dipity";

        System.out.println("Enter the value the numbers for " +      dingdong.name);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter the value for a: ");
        dingdong.a = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter the value for b: ");
        dingdong.b = in.nextDouble();

        calculatedAverage = dingdong.calc_average();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to search for libraries for spreadsheet manipulation in Java? (Hint: in StackOverflow, that would be off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I have had a lot of success with the Apache POI libraries. Very easy to work with and understand.

Specific to Excel and spreadsheets, use the [HSSF & XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html) libraries